# Schedule form data push to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Nodejs I have a form which takes in details of articles.Then they get added to the unpublished list from which i have to manually press the publish button to publish them.

### What i am looking for is a way to somehow add an option in the form where user can select the publish time and at that time the article gets published

So basically a scheduler to take in id and time of the article and execute the publish request at that time.

#### This is how i publish the article

```
router.get('/publish/:id', function(req, res){

  Article.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: { published : true }},function(err, article){
    res.redirect('/Article/viewArticle');
  });
});
//
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always persist your state (the publishing time) in the database. If you would start a timer in NodeJS, and someone restarts your server, that timer is lost and the article too.

Now to store the publishing time persistently, just add a field, e.g. `publishedAt` to the Article:

```
 Article.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: { publishedAt : date }}, function(err, article){
   res.redirect('/Article/viewArticle');
 });
```

Now when querying for an article on a public page, filter out by publishing date:

```
  Article.find({ publishedAt: { $lte: new Date() })
```

Comment: Okay so this solves half of my problem,how can i automate the Article querying.So that it checks every certain minutes and if there are any articles whose publish date is due it publishes them

Comment: What do you mean by "publishing"?

Comment: Basically i have an apt.get request which takes in id param and searches that id in the database and changes its published filed from false to true.So what i need is to do this when the current time and published time are same.This is what i meant but scheduling the publish

Comment: That makes little sense. If you query for `{ published: true }` you could just directly query for `{ publishedAt: { $lte: new Date() }`}

Comment: Querying is not the problem,i am able to publish the article if i click on the publish button.The problem is that i dont want to publish every article manually so i want to automate this process based on the published date i have set on them.So if an article has tomorrow's publish date it should automatically get published tomorrow.